# Turning on OpenGL Debugging in Android to debug a texture loading problem

Tags: android, debugging, opengl-es

I am getting an error when I turn on the opengl debugging flags to try and debug a problem with texture loading.

On the android development blog, the following [code snippet](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/introducing-glsurfaceview.html) demonstrates how to turn on debugging

```
//constructor
    public MyCustomSurfaceView(Context context) { 
        super(context);
        // Turn on error-checking and logging
        setDebugFlags(DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR | DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS);
        mRenderer = new ClearRenderer();
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }
```

I am trying to turn on debugging using the following related method directly in my activities onCreate function:

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
            glSurfaceView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR | GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS);
            glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new GLRenderer(this));
            setContentView(glSurfaceView);
        }
```

My program runs when the line `glSurfaceView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR | GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS)` is changed to `glSurfaceView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS)`. But when I add it back I get the following error:

```
07-16 08:57:56.009: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14959): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 9
07-16 08:57:56.009: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14959): android.opengl.GLException: invalid value
07-16 08:57:56.009: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14959):     at android.opengl.GLErrorWrapper.checkError(GLErrorWrapper.java:62)
07-16 08:57:56.009: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14959):     at android.opengl.GLErrorWrapper.glEnable(GLErrorWrapper.java:270)
07-16 08:57:56.009: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14959):     at android.opengl.GLLogWrapper.glEnable(GLLogWrapper.java:1552)
07-16 08:57:56.009: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14959):     at android.com.gl_tutorials.GLRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(GLRenderer.java:64)
07-16 08:57:56.009: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14959):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1317)
07-16 08:57:56.009: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14959):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)
```

And the debugging data looks like this:

```
07-16 08:57:55.979: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(14959): glGenTextures(1, [0], 0) returns {
07-16 08:57:55.979: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(14959):  [0] = 1
07-16 08:57:55.979: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(14959): };
07-16 08:57:55.979: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(14959): glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
07-16 08:57:55.979: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(14959): glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
07-16 08:57:55.979: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(14959): glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
07-16 08:57:55.979: VERBOSE/GLSurfaceView(14959): glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

When the glSurfaceView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR | GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS); isn't there my shape shows up as a green square (it is supposed to be textured). When I add the line the program crashes. My full code is below.

Base Activity:

```
package android.com.gl_tutorials;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Run extends Activity {

    /** the opengl view */
    private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);

            //the line of death:
            glSurfaceView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR | GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_LOG_GL_CALLS);

            glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new GLRenderer(this));
            setContentView(glSurfaceView);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            glSurfaceView.onResume();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            glSurfaceView.onPause();
        }
}
```

OpenGL Renderer:

```
package android.com.gl_tutorials;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.util.Log;

public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {
    private Square square;
    private Context context;

    public GLRenderer(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        square = new Square();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        //Log.v("Tutorial","onDrawFrame Triggered");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        square.draw(gl);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        Log.v("Tutorial","onSurfaceChanged Triggered");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(height ==0) {
            height=1;
        }

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width/(float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig arg1) {
        Log.v("Tutorial","onSurfaceCreated Triggered");

        //Load the texture for the square
        square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); //Enable Texture Mapping
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH); //Enable Smooth Shading
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0); //Black Background
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f); //Depth buffer setup
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); //Really nice perspective calculations, uneeded for what I'm doing

    }

}
```

Square Object

```
package android.com.gl_tutorials;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;

public class Square {
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

    private float vertices[] = { //x,y,z
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, //V1 - bottom left
            -1.0f, 1f, 0.0f, // V2 - top left
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // V3 bottom right  
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f //V4 top right
    };

    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;
    private float texture[] = {
            //Mapping coordinates for the vertices
            0.0f, 1.0f, //top left (V2)
            0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left (V1)
            1.0f, 1.0f, // top right (V4)
            1.0f, 0.0f //bottom right (V3)  
    };

    public Square() {
        ByteBuffer vertexByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4);
        vertexByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = vertexByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.position(0);

    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        // bind the generated texture, make it active
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // Point to our buffers
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        //Set the face rotation
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

        //gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

        // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length/3);

        //Disable the client state before leaving
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }

    private int[] textures = new int[1];

    public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context){
        //loading texture
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bg_bismarck);

        //generate one texture pointer
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        // ..and bind it to our array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]); //A bound texture is an active texture

        // create nearest filtered texture
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST); //This is where the scaling algorithms are
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST); //This is where the scaling algorithms are

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,bitmap,0);

        bitmap.recycle();
    }

}
```

Comment: im having the same problem, did you find a fix?

Comment: No, as I continued to work on my program I made a changes and the error mysteriously went away. I don't how becuase I turned debugging off for a long time. It must be something strange, rare, and difficult to duplicate.

Comment: Turning the error logger on in OpenGL seems to be causing a problem with me too on Android 2.2 and 2.3. Devices I tested with were a Galaxy S and Galaxy S2. I got a crash in Galaxy S and Y. Galaxy S2 would just show a black screen without a texture.